# Remote control Flash presentation

Tags: php, flash

Firstly, I want to thank you guys for all the help you've provided me over the years, I've been a lurker but would like to contribute to people's questions now that I have some knowledge.

My question is:

My friend has asked me to help him develop some kind of remote control for a Flash presentation, such in the way that he can send parameters to the Flash file remotely using a PHP page or something and tell the Flash file to play a specific point in that file.

He is on a judging panel for an animation awards ceremony he has previously won, the organisers would like his character to be on the panel also, providing feedback to the nominated participants.  So essentially we need a set amount of responses and for my friend to be able to pick a response and the flash file to play it.

The process flow would be as follows:

HTML page on mobile -> response selected -> response sent to remote server -> flash file playing specific response.

Has anyone ever heard of something like this been done?  Or if you could point me in the right direction of what to search on Google that would be brilliant.

Once again, many thanks for all your help.

Luke

Comment: Which version of Flash and ActionScript would you be using? The answer is not hard to script but it matters which programming language you're interested in ....

Comment: It will be ActionScript 3.0, haven't really had a thought about which version of Flash but ideally the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doable, however.... do you really need an IP solution? Can't you just have someone in the room?

Comment: Well the animator is the character really and as he's on the panel, we can't really have him messing about with a Mac.  Ideally he'd have his phone under the table and no-one would really know what was happening.

Comment: And nobody but him can control it?

Comment: Well since the character will be responding to questions, animations etc., ideally the animator will be in control.

Comment: So, he will be responding both as himself and the character? Or just the character? Regardless, I think you will be far better served by doing this with keyboard and mose events. If controller and playback are in the same room there is no reason whatsoever to go through a network.